# Firebase Sorting using keys in reverse order

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use keys to sort my data from latest to oldest. My first option is to use unique keys in reverse order(latest will be on top), so first I used negative timeStamp as keys. But keys in firebase are string so it won't work. That's why I decided to use `[9999999999999 - date.now()]` as key in firebase and it works(rendered reversely). Is it safe to use this method? Why using child is the best way to sort data? Why not keys?

```
firebase.database().ref('saved_phrases')
    .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .child([9999999999999-Date.now()]).set(
      "phrase"
    )
```

Comment: This is pretty vague; what does *push keys in reverse order* mean exactly and more importantly why would you want to do that? Also, using keys for ordering may not be the best idea - you may be better off storing a timestamp as a child node and ordering by that. If you store a + child node and then a - child node you can read them ascending or descending at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally valid to create your own keys, as long as your app guarantees that these keys are unique. So if a user in your app can only ever create a single saved phrase per millisecond (the granularity of `Date.now()`), you should have no chance of getting the same key multiple times. But you should only use these keys if you can guarantee these keys will be unique - not just now but also for the future of your app.

If you're not completely certain of this, consider storing the timestamp as a property, the inverse timestamp as another property, and then use `orderByChild()` to get the behavior you need.